# addSubview to a view - appear as PageCurlDown

Tags: iphone, ios, animation, core-animation

I am adding a view (lets say redView) to self.view in a view controller.

Now the problem is i want the page curl down animation when the redView is added.

Is it possible to get that ?

Comment: Google for *addSubview animated*, first result is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337408/addsubview-animation).

Comment: @lawicko : Thanks for the link.  I want the redView to curlDown on adding to self.view .

Answer (score 1):

Sampath,

I do this in an app I am developing at the moment.

This is what I did and it works fine:

```
[self.view insertSubview:redView atIndex:0]

[UIView transitionWithView:self.view 
                  duration:1.0 
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlDown 
                animations:^{ [[[self.view subviews] objectAtIndex:1] removeFromSuperview];} 
                completion:NULL];
```

Hope it works for you.

Keith

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Please refer fourth comment un above answer .

Answer (score 1):

if redView is subClass of UIViewController.

First method

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown
                       forView:redView.view
                         cache:YES];

[self.view addSubview:redView.view];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Second Method

```
RedView *viewController = [[RedView alloc] initWithNibName:@"RedView" bundle:nil];
    [viewController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl];
    [self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

if redView is subClass of UIView.

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown
                       forView:redView
                         cache:YES];

[self.view addSubview:redView];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: These seem a bit complicated to me, and I think beginAnimations and commitAnimations have been deprecated in favour of block animation as  I used in my answer.

Comment: Its not depreciated, it says discouraged in ios 4 nd later

Comment: @Krrish: Thanks a lot for the answer. The answer i need is "if redView is subClass of UIView". I tried it . It first shows the view and then performs the animation. I want it like perform animation and then show the view. That is because  self.view contains some data and redView contains some other data. User has to feel the change in data on animation.

Comment: @Krrish : The image is like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551521/is-it-possible-to-get-a-catransition-animation-as-uiimage

Comment: @Sampath , I am not sure what exactly ur need is. In the third line of the code Just pass cache:NO instead of cache:YES, then the data in the view will start loading while animating page curl.